# How to construct a JSON when [keys] are seperated from [values] inside Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have been struggling with this for a long time to construct an output where my [key] is separated from my array value, please help to share your expertise.

Below is the response, i have received from Azure Alert and I'm looking forward to create an output (refer Expected Output image).

```
{
    "tables": [
      {
        "columns": [
          {
            "name": "task",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "environment",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "workspace",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "name": "PrimaryResult",
        "rows": [
          [
            "job_name_1",
            "PRODUCTION",
            "WORKSPACE-1",
          ],
          [
            "job_name_2",
            "TEST",
            "WORKSPACE-2",
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Inside Logic App. I have parsed the json and used a lot of for each loop variations but, every single time, i get stuck in traversing the rows as its a 2d array. Even though, i traverse them, i cannot associate them with columns. Any alternative approaches will be appreciated ?

**Input**

**Expected Output**

```
[ 
   {
      "task": "job_name_1",
      "environment": "PRODUCTION",
      "workspace" : "WORKSPACE-1"
   },
   {
      "task": "job_name_2",
      "environment": "TEST",
      "workspace" : "WORKSPACE-2"
   }
]
```

Comment: Can you please supply the JSON as text, not as an image? In both instances, i.e. input and expected output.

Comment: done. please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be lying if I said this was straight forward but you can load the below definition into your tenant and see a working version.

***Note:** I made the assumption that you only ever have one table in your top level array given that's what you provided in your question.*

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_Each_Row": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_To_Transformed_Array": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Transformed Array",
                            "value": "@variables('Row Object')"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "For_Each_Column": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    },
                    "For_Each_Column": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Add_Property_To_Temp_Row_Object": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "Temp Row Object",
                                    "value": "@addProperty(variables('Row Object'), variables('Columns')?[variables('Column Index')]['name'], items('For_Each_Column'))"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "SetVariable"
                            },
                            "Increment_Column_Index": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "Column Index",
                                    "value": 1
                                },
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Set_Row_Object_From_Temp_Row_Object": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "type": "IncrementVariable"
                            },
                            "Set_Row_Object_From_Temp_Row_Object": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "Row Object",
                                    "value": "@variables('Temp Row Object')"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Add_Property_To_Temp_Row_Object": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "type": "SetVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "foreach": "@item()",
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Reset_Column_Index": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Foreach"
                    },
                    "Reset_Column_Index": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Column Index",
                            "value": 0
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Reset_Temp_Row_Object": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    },
                    "Reset_Row_Object": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Row Object",
                            "value": {}
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    },
                    "Reset_Temp_Row_Object": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Temp Row Object",
                            "value": {}
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Reset_Row_Object": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@variables('Rows')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Column_Index": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "concurrency": {
                        "repetitions": 1
                    }
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_Column_Index": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Column Index",
                            "type": "integer"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Temp_Row_Object": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Columns": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Columns",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": "@variables('Data')?['tables'][0]['columns']"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Data": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Data": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Data",
                            "type": "object",
                            "value": {
                                "tables": [
                                    {
                                        "columns": [
                                            {
                                                "name": "task",
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "name": "environment",
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "name": "workspace",
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "name": "PrimaryResult",
                                        "rows": [
                                            [
                                                "job_name_1",
                                                "PRODUCTION",
                                                "WORKSPACE-1"
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                "job_name_2",
                                                "TEST",
                                                "WORKSPACE-2"
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Row_Object": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Row Object",
                            "type": "object"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Transformed_Array": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Rows": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Rows",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": "@variables('Data')?['tables'][0]['rows']"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Columns": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Temp_Row_Object": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Temp Row Object",
                            "type": "object",
                            "value": {}
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Row_Object": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Transformed_Array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Transformed Array",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Rows": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Result": {
                "inputs": "@variables('Transformed Array')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_Each_Row": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

The main challenges I see with having to do this are ...

1. The lack of ability to self reference.  Because of that, I had to use a `Row Object` in conjunction with a `Temp Row Object` when adding the property each time.
2. The amount of nesting is a little hard to follow but it works.
3. Performance will be a real burden if you have a lot of rows.

One thing to note is the outer `For Each` action needs to have the concurrency set to 1, if it's not, you'll run into problems.

This is the end result as you were wanting ...

[image: Result]

Comment: For Sure, Mr. Skin you've put a lot of efforts into this. 

I'm truly thankful. I have adjusted the solution as per my requirement. But, I must say there's lot to learn from the way you implemented it. I wish if i could thank in person. 

Merry Christmas to you.

Comment: No worries @SantoshGadhave, I appreciate your words.  You have a Merry Xmas too.